# msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail Not sending messages when using isnull

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail to send email based upon query results.  It works fine until I used and isnull in my query. The query returns the right results but  a message is not triggered. When the field in question is not null it works fine.

I want to validate builddate against checkdate.  When they do not match I want to send an email. I used isnull for cases when the table did not populate and builddate is null.

My base query is as follows:

```
 SELECT 
 ISNULL(MAX(convert(date,Builddate)),DATEADD(YEAR,-10,GETDATE())) AS 
 [builddate],
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),121)AS [checkdate]
 FROM dbo. XXXX_BPCCustomer_Test
 HAVING  ISNULL(MAX(convert(date,Builddate)),DATEADD(YEAR,-10,GETDATE())) 
 <>CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),121)
```

the results are builddate=2010-01-03 and checkdate = 2020-01-3

the code that pushes the email is as follows:

```
 DECLARE             @recordcount INT

 SELECT @recordcount = ISNULL(COUNT(*),0) 


 FROM [YCH-REPORTING\YCHANALYTICS].[x3v7].[dbo].[Dataset_BPCCustomer_Test]

 HAVING  ISNULL(MAX(convert(date,Builddate)),DATEADD(YEAR,-10,GETDATE())) 
 <>CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),121)



 IF (@recordcount > 0)

 BEGIN

 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
  @profile_name = 'SQL Mail',
  @recipients = 'john.XXXXXXXXX.com;XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  @query = 'SELECT 
        ISNULL(MAX(convert(date,Builddate)),DATEADD(YEAR,-10,GETDATE())) AS 
  [builddate],
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),121)AS 
  [checkdate],"Dataset_BPCCustomer_Test" as [Table]
        FROM [XXXXXX\YCHANALYTICS].[x3XX].[dbo]. 
  [Dataset_BPCCustomer_Test]
        HAVING  
  ISNULL(MAX(convert(date,Builddate)),DATEADD(YEAR,-10,GETDATE())) 
  <>CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),121)'
        ,

  @subject = ' DataSet did not update or isnull',
--@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
--@query_result_header = 0,
  @body =0;
  END
```

It appears that it is not processing the isnull statement?  Any suggestions and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are double-quotes (`"Dataset_BPCCustomer_Test"`) inside `@query`, making the statement incorrect.

Those should each be two single quotes (apostrophes):

```
 @query = 'SELECT 
        ISNULL(MAX(convert(date,Builddate)),DATEADD(YEAR,-10,GETDATE())) AS 
  [builddate],
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),121)AS 
  [checkdate],''Dataset_BPCCustomer_Test'' as [Table]
        FROM [XXXXXX\YCHANALYTICS].[x3XX].[dbo]. 
  [Dataset_BPCCustomer_Test]
        HAVING  
  ISNULL(MAX(convert(date,Builddate)),DATEADD(YEAR,-10,GETDATE())) 
  <>CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),121)'
```

Comment: when I place single quotes around 'Dataset_BPCCustomer_Test' as [Table] I get the following error Incorrect syntax near 'Dataset_BPCCustomer_Test'.

Comment: I tried removing the field in question (''Dataset_BPCCustomer_Test'' as [Table]) and now the query returns complete but does not send an email.  The dates do not match so I am not sure why it is not sending the message. Any suggestions ? thanks

Comment: I would suggest verifying that you can send a simple email without the query.  I worry about the `@body =0` because it's supposed to be string.

Comment: I truncated my test data so I would get a null value in my build date.  It does not send an email when running isnull peace.  If builddate is populated and checkdate <> it does send email.